# How to I get the hover to only hover over an SVG file and not the empty space beside it?

Tags: html, css, svg, hyperlink, hover

I have a triangle shaped SVG file that I'm trying to make change colors when hovered over, as well as be a clickable link. When I hover over it, it does exactly that, however since it is not a rectangle, the empty space is also triggering the hover function, even though the svg is not being hovered over directly.

Is there a way to make the invisible space not trigger the hover?
Is that an SVG specific limitation?
And if this can be resolved, is it the same resolution if the image was a png and not an svg?

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: Hi. Can you add your code to the question, so that we can see where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1):

The `<svg>` will always take up a square space on the HTML page.

In this example the parent element of the `<path>` is an anchor element and the hover style is on the `<path>`.

```css
path:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6 5" width="200">
  <a href="#">
    <path fill="navy" d="M 3 0 L 0 5 L 6 5 Z"/>
  </a>
</svg>
```